# Display post image in a size defined by add_image_size()

Tags: images

As I already used the featured image for something else, I want to add another image and display it in one of the sizes defined in my functions.php with add_image_size().

I know how to do that with a featured image : I just have to use the_post_thumbnail() function and indicate the size I want in the parameters. But what about a post image ?

Comment: Are you trying to display this image programmatically (i.e. directly in a template file), or as part of the Post Content?

Answer (score 2):

Try using `wp_get_attachment_image()` ([Codex ref](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image))?

```
echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachmentid, $imagesize );
```

Where `$attachmentid` is the attachment ID, and `$imagesize` is the name of the image size in the `add_image_size()` call.

**EDIT**

For a custom-field stored image SRC URL, I'm not finding any way to make use of intermediate image sizes defined via `add_image_size()` (or even the default image sizes). Pretty much all of the related functions eventually require an *attachment ID*.

Comment: I'm stupid, it's not a post image that I want to display but an image whose URL has been added in a custom field !

Comment: Any particular reason you can't use the Media Manager for post-attached images, rather than custom fields? But, you're storing an IMG SRC as a custom field? Let me update my answer...

Comment: well I don't want the image to appear in the post content, I just use this image to feature the post (and a small piece of its textual content only) on the front page.

I use its featured image to feature it elsewhere in the front page, for a different reason (that doesn't matter much here)

So there is no solution to my problem ?

Comment: As far as I can tell, no. You can use any arbitrarily sized image in a custom field, and you can display it in your template, but I can't find any way to tie the size of a custom-field image to an `add_image_size()` image size.

Comment: Gosh, I'll have to find another solution then. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, more or less. The $name parameter of `add_image_size` with can be called like this,

```
the_post_thumbnail( 'your_add_image_size_name' );
```

Comment: He said he's already used the featured image (i.e. the post thumbnail) for another purpose, so I presume this need would be for any arbitrary image *other than* the featured image.

Answer (score 0):

Within you functions.php, first define your custom thumbnail image:

add_image_size( 'custom_thumbnail', 300, 200, true );

Then use the following code to retrieve this thumbnail size:

$image_data = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment->ID , 'custom_thumbnail');

There is no post image, maybe you mean the post featured image? If so you can get the attachment id using this:

$thumbnail_id = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_thumbnail_id', TRUE);

then use

$image_data = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumbnail_id , 'custom_thumbnail');

Or get all post images:

$argv = array(
                        'post_parent' => $post->ID,
                        'post_type' => 'attachment',
                        'post_mime_type' => 'image',
                        'orderby' => 'menu_order'
                        );
        $attachments = get_children($argv);

Answer (score 0):

You need to think a bit different to solve this one, at the moment I see two different approaches to the problem.

You can use some css to resize the image, just assign a class to the image based on your `add_image_size` preferences and set some css rules to give the desired size, not a real resize, but sometimes it's enough.

Or you can use some third party script like [tinythumb](http://www.binarymoon.co.uk/projects/timthumb/) to generate a real thumbnail.